# Update a user entity field in JPQL with IN clause

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

I have a class user where I need to update the **loginCount** and **lastLogin**.
Some users have already logged in and updated data, so I want to update there loginCount to 1.

I tried to use JPQL.

I created a query, where I am sending **loginCount** variable = **1**, **lastLogin** as **currentDate** and **ids** as a combination of all ids as CommaSeparatedString.

```
@Query("update User u set u.loginCount = :loginCount, u.lastLogin = :lastLogin where u.id IN (:ids)")
void updateUserInitialLoginCount(@Param("loginCount") Long loginCount, @Param("lastLogin") Date lastLogin, @Param("ids") String ids);
```

I want to use 'IN' clause but here I got a problem that by to use IN clause I have to have a comma-delimited-string but my id which I am finding is of type Long.

> ```
> ERROR:
> Parameter value [1,2] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long(n/a)]
> ```

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: You need to pass `ids` as a `List<Long> ids` and change the param type of `ids` in the method param as well.

Comment: Thanks  Erfan Ahmed Emon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass list of long as Param for ids instead of String.

```
@Query("update User u set u.loginCount = :loginCount, u.lastLogin = :lastLogin where u.id IN (:ids)")
void updateUserInitialLoginCount(@Param("loginCount") Long loginCount, @Param("lastLogin") Date lastLogin, @Param("ids") List<Long> ids);
```

And when you call this method create an array list of Long and add the ids in it and pass as parameter.

Comment: Thanks, Pooja, I should have known that. TCH